# Exception when resource is defined in the control library and is referenced from main app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have two projects in my solution: main WPF app and control library. Inside control library there are three resource dictionaries: Colors.xaml, Styles.xaml and Generic.xaml with the following contents:

*Colors.xaml*

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush"
                     Color="Yellow" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

*Styles.xaml*

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
           x:Key="DefaultTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource MyBrush}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

*Generic.xaml*

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Color.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now, I want to add this Generic.xaml into application resources and use the textbox style inside main window like this:

*App.xaml*

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/ClassLibrary;component/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="525">
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBox}" />
</Window>
```

BUT the problem is that it leads to exception

**'{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'Background'**.

At the same time using `<TextBox Background="{StaticResource MyBrush}"/>` works fine. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It's the order of inheritance amigo. For your example to work you would need to go Colors->Styles->Generic, not Colors&&Styles->Generic. As it sits, Styles knows nothing about your Color resources.

Comment: This is just a simplification. In the real app I have more dictionaries and I'm forced to duplicate some of them inside others e.g. Buttons.xaml has reference to Colors.xaml, Controls.xaml has reference to both Buttons.xaml and Colors.xaml something else has reference to all of them etc. I would like to avoid creating multiple dictionaries with the same source

Comment: Nah you shouldn't have to duplicate anything....but the one's with dependencies on elements in another have to reference them. Just Avoid "circular" dependencies. So for example, if you have one Colors dict, and then Buttons and Styles use stuff in Colors, then you would just ref it in the MerdedDictionaries of both Buttons and Styles. Think top down inheritance.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something but isn't having Colors inside both Buttons and Styles actually duplicates Colors in memory?

Comment: Oh no it will, to get around that you have to [workaround](http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html) potential issues like that but things still have to find what they're looking for one way or another right? Or at least as far as I know. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it seems like a decent workaround)